# CMD + r not working in Xcode version 10.1 in Mojave (10.14.2)

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave, xcode10.1

After updating the Xcode <kbd>⌘R</kbd> not working in Mojave (10.14.2).

I have downloaded the Xcode the latest Xcode and updated the Mac OS X version also

Mac OS X version: 10.14.2
Xcode Version: 10.1

Comment: Go to Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings.  Search for the command-name using the field at the top-right, then double click in the key field and type the key you want to use and Check if Run is available or no,

Comment: Already I have Command+r  in the Key Bindings, But it not working for me

Comment: Is the Run button active? Does `Product`>`Run` (menu) work?

Comment: When I hit the run button it working fine. But If I click on Command+ r and Command + d it not working.

Comment: Simulator not working in command+r (refreshing)